# Why does this hand tool have this component?

Tags: motor

I was fixing a corded electric handheld grinder (110Vac) the other day and there was something inside that I cannot explain.

The live and neutral supply into the grinder from the cord runs through a metal ring like component and are both wrapped around it twice.

Why is this done?

***I will upload an image of it later on when I can, as it is on my phone and I have no Wi-Fi at present.***

**EDIT: ADDED IMAGE**

[image]

Comment: As per Frog's answer, the component in your picture is a ferrite ring which is used as a common mode choke to reduce radiation of electronic noise from the power cord. An AM radio is a good tool for sniffing for this sort of noise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not wishing to jump the gun, that sounds like a ferrite ring that’s there to minimise the amount of radio-frequency interference that’s sent back into the AC supply.

Comment: That's what it does, and the term for it would be common-mode choke or common-mode filter.